# accepts_nested_attributes_for allow_destroy doesn't work with scoped validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, nested-forms

I am trying to puzzle out why the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` will not destroy a record when it receives a hash like this:

```
{project_parcels_attributes"=>[{"parcel_id"=>"680060", "_destroy"=>"1"}, {"parcel_id"=>"680088"}]}
```

The context of use is as follows. There is a Project model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :project_parcels
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_parcels, allow_destroy: true
end

class ProjectParcels < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :project
   belongs_to :parcel

   validates :parcel_id, uniqueness: {scope: :project_id}
end
```

Then I call it from a form like this:

```
@project.update_attributes({"project_parcels_attributes"=>[{"parcel_id"=>"680060", "_destroy"=>"1"}, {"parcel_id"=>"680088"}]})
```

Yet, it doesn't work. The validation stops the record from being destroyed. But when I remove validation, the record gets added multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add the id of the child object by an hidden_field tag

```
<%= f.hidden_field :id %>
```

and then update with the id :

```
{project_parcels_attributes"=>[{id: an_id, "parcel_id"=>"680060", "_destroy"=>"1"}, {id: an_id, "parcel_id"=>"680088"}]}
```

Comment: Also, the example in the documentation doesn't mention the id field being necessary. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods-label-One-to-many

Comment: update_only section speaks about one-to-one relationships... it is quite the same for many-to-many relationships

Comment: double checked... I have a functionnal example

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Guess I need to bite the bullet then. Thanks!